# ¿Como usar el primer renglon de un archivo CSV como nombre de las columnas en SQL, especificamente en SSMS?

Tags: sql, csv, ssms

Estoy importando un archivo CSV a SQL usando SSMS, pero al hacerlo no me detecta el primer renglon de mi archivo csv como los nombres de las columnas. ¿Cómo debería importar el archivo para que el primer renglon se vea como los encabezados?
Lo estoy importando como un archivo flat a una base de datos, y lo estoy subiendo como destino el propio server de SQL (sin usar código)

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes. Podrías por favor ampliar un poco el detalle de cómo estás intentando importar el archivo? Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: ¿Qué estás usando para importarlo? Hay varias formas de hacerlo.

Comment: Lo estoy importando como un archivo flat a una base de datos, y lo estoy subiendo como destino el propio server de SQL